# Avoided crossings - number of conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

In the avoided-crossing argument for a two-state model (von Neumann-Wigner theorem, c.f. Landau-Lifshitz III, §79, see also [Avoided Crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoided_crossing)) it is assumed that one needs to satisfy two conditions for the levels to cross - thus if there are k parameters available the crossing will be a k-2 dimensional manifold.

However, if one writes a general Hermitian matrix as
\begin{equation}
H=\begin{pmatrix}
E_1 & V\\
V^* & E_2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
the eigenvalues $E_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}(E_1+E_2)\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(E_1-E_2)+\lvert V\rvert^2}$ only cross if $\bf{three}$ conditions are satisfied ($E_1-E_2=0$; $\Re(V)=0$; $\Im(V)=0$) thus I would assume that the crossing would generically be a k-3 dimensional manifold. In the Wikipedia article and in LL it is assumed that V can be written real if one chooses real giving the result above.

What allows us to assume real $V$ and thus reduce the number of conditions by 1?

I am particularly interested in the case of electron bands in a solid where there are three parameters corresponding to the crystal momentum. Here people seem to require three conditions (e.g. in the conditions for a Weyl point to arise in a low symmetry point in the Brillouin zone: the Hermitian matrix is written in the Pauli matrix basis $H=f(\mathbf{k})\sigma_0+\sum_i g_i (\mathbf{k})\sigma_i$, then the three conditions are simply $g_i(\mathbf{k})=0$. Then generically there will be touching points of the bands and not lines, just like I would expect for a Weyl metal).

Comment: If you rewrite $V$ as $|V|\exp(i\phi)$ then you only need $|V|=0$ and $\Delta E = 0$.

Comment: Ah okay. How does this then apply to the context of bandstructure with three tunable parameters? In the literature (e.g. in this review, chapter II, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.2272.pdf) it seems to be assumed there are three conditions to be satisfied, as in the second part of my question.